# Flux without React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm in a project and my task is to build drop-down lists that lets user say his location without free text. I came to a point where I think that Flux is a really good way to built it, but I do not want to use React because of the dependencies issues. I would like to know if it is possible to build a flux app without React? And if it make sense?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Flux without React since it really is just a data-flow architecture. Pretty much everything will be exactly the same -- except you won't be using React components. You would add a changeListener to the store, passing it a callback function to use when it processes an action.

I'm surprised, though, that you're concerned about using React due to dependency issues. What issues are those?

Comment: I make part off a big project called Catalogue, which is a platform to gather hospital databases information. They had a problem which was that they asked the user location with free text, that was bad because the user could say whatever he wants, didn't follow a standard. So, I am implementing that dropdown list system that limits user response in a certain format. I saw that flux fit the problem, but I would have React. My tutor said that It was a good idea, but he did not want to bring more dependencies to the project, just because of a little widget.